# using custom object ID with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a API.I am using mongo DB and mongoose as ORM tool with express. I want to use customer object id for my schema.

I want to implement CURD operation on the schema with customer id. The custom id can be anything for ex: `'someid'` or a Number like `1`.

The users can query the API using those Id's

I am using `Model.create()` method to insert and `update()` method to update and `remove()` method to delete and `findById` to find by id

The Schema is defined as

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    name : {type: String},
    email: {type : String}
});
```

EDIT: 
If the ID is not present then generate an auto id

Comment: Add `_id: {type: String, required: true}` ?

Comment: @Wilbeibi After save it is returning me an hexadecimal string, as string. I want to return to client the original id that they passed

Comment: @Wilbeibi If I don't specify the _id field then required validation will fail. I mentioned that if I don't specify the _id field I want the mongo db driver to auto generate the id field

Comment: _id: {type: XXX, default: your_variable}

Comment: @Wilbeibi This is not working. I am inserting in batch then it will throw dup_key error.

Comment: Sure _id should be identical.

Comment: `_id` must be unique - it's the "primary key" for the documents in SQL speak. I would caution you against using a distinguished field like `_id` as a user-settable value, in particular because it looks like your documents aren't uniquely keyed on `customer_id`, so it cannot be used as a value for `_id`. Use another field called `customer_id`. You can use the `default` option in Mongoose to autogenerate.

Comment: @wdberkeley It's working I have to use
{ _id : String, required: true, default: function() { return mongoose.Types.ObjectID(); }}